# my function to validate a checkbox in a form not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check term function not working to validate checkbox in HTML form with jQuery...

Here is my code, click the checkbox and click outside to trigger the validation:

```js
function check_term() {
  var term = $("#term").val()
  if (term.checked = true) {
    $("term_error_message").hide();
  } else {
    $("term_error_message").html("Please accept our terms and conditions");
    $("term_error_message").show();
    error_term = true;
  }
  console.log("error_term is " + error_term);
}

$("#term_error_message").hide()
var error_term = false;
$("#term").focusout(function() {
  check_term()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>  
  <input id="term" type="checkbox"> I Accept the terms and conditions
</div>
<div id="term_error_message"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , please include your HTML code as well as explanation of "its not working". What is the error? "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem."

Comment: `term.checked = true` <-- assignment, not comparison!

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you are assigning the value `true` to `term.checked`. You should use the `===` comparison operator instead of `=`.

Like this: `if (term.checked === true) {`

I don't know if that will solve all your problems, but it's a start.

Visit this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison

Comment: thanks man. i realise the error, i missed out the #selector on my id

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
function check_term() {
  var term = $("#term");
  if (term.prop("checked")) {
    $("#term_error_message").hide();
  } else {
    $("#term_error_message").html("Please accept our terms and conditions");
    $("#term_error_message").show();
  }
  return term.prop("checked");
}

var error_term = false;
$("#term_error_message").hide()
$("#term").blur(function() {
  error_term = check_term();
});
```

Assigning the Value of `#term` would give you a String, not an Object. So, `term.checked` would be `undefined`. You will want to check the Property of a checkbox to see if it checked or not. `.prop()`, as a Getter will return `true` or `false` for the property checked.

You also need to use the proper Selector in your jQuery. I think you also mean the `blur` callback versus `focusout`.

You can also use `.is()` like so.

```
function check_term() {
  if ($("#term").is(":checked")) {
    $("#term_error_message").hide();
  } else {
    $("#term_error_message").html("Please accept our terms and conditions");
    $("#term_error_message").show();
  }
  return $("#term").is(":checked");
}
```

This is also going to return `true` or `false`.